# Single sign on server/page

Tags: .net, mobile, authentication, xamarin, cross-domain

I need a cross-domain web to mobile app single sign-on solution. I have an app that currently authenticates a user using the LoginProvider class in .net. Each request has an "X-ZUMO-AUTH" header added to it.

My problem is that I am about to add a few more mobile and web apps that would share the same login credentials.

How can I go about verifying users across multiple domains? Do I setup a stand-alone verification application that pushes out a token or is there some library that keeps a session open for doing this?

What do people use on .net to assign a single sign on to users? mind you that this process would have to work with mobile applications "iOS and Android" as well as web apps.

I was looking at this : [SSO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972971.aspx#singlesignon_topic9) and I am not too sure yet if this is a good way to go about it.

My current app uses: Xamarin with an Azure back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally recommend using something like thinktecture, because most of the work is already done, and it help in supporting many ways for login and all are available and documented.

look at the documentation and the project [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3)
 also you can follow the samples [here](https://github.com/identityserver/IdentityServer3.Samples) , i don't know how your apps(android and IOS will be build ) but the Identity server can act as a service.

Comment: This is a nice find. I will look into the documentation; if no-one else comes up with something of this level I will grant you the bounty.

Comment: Best open source SSO solution ever. Thank you! I hope you get up-voted until the end of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an API that handles authentication. The API could handle both user based and device-based authentication (you will need to generate a unique device id and store it in your database). You should also pass in application or device type to the API for reporting purpose.

Comment: I was considering this, but my biggest worry is the overhead of checking against a Third API in between applications. Won't this be too much of an issue on Role Management and Identity for the different HTTP Requests? Or is there a unified way to produce identical Identifications tokens in .NET?